# Can't find class when compiling file in terminal but works when executing through the IDE

Tags: java

I'm encountering an issue while trying to run my Java program from the terminal. My Alice.java file references a class DES.java located in the same package.

When attempting to compile and run the program using java Alice.java in the terminal, I get a "cannot find symbol" error for the DES class.
[IDE Screenshot with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur5bB.png)

I suspect this may be a package-related issue. Initially, I had both files in the default package (src folder), and the program ran smoothly in the terminal. However, after moving them into a package named project1, the terminal compilation fails.

**Everything works fine when executed through the IDE.**

Comment: Don't ignore the directory/package structure and the need to use classpath.

Comment: `javac -d . *.java; java -cp . project1.Alice`

Comment: Try to `set classpath=./` (type forward slash instead of slash) before running